# In what ways could coastal cities like New York/Boston/Miami mitigate future sea level rises and maintain current dry land area?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, environmental-engineering

We've all read articles on rising sea levels and the impact it will have on coastal cities in the coming decades. There are [even maps](http://ss2.climatecentral.org/#8/42.332/-71.020?show=satellite&projections=0-RCP85-SLR&level=5&unit=feet&pois=hide) that illustrate how varying levels of rising seas will impact the dry land in and around these cities.

My question is, aside from deep carbon cuts that can help postpone or reverse rising sea level trends, what sorts of engineering proposals could these cities undertake to maintain their current areas of dry land? Whether its constructing massive gates around the shores of the city limits or something else entirely, could we avoid large portions of these urban areas going underwater in the future?

I'm gonna go ahead and say spare no expense when it comes to strategies.

Comment: In general, we only handle questions here that have identifiable 'correct' answers. Entire books and research papers are written about this question and there are tons of possible strategies and ways to evaluate which is best. Because of that, any answers would be rambling discussions, not definitive answers. If you have a question about a specific strategy or aspect of the problem, I'm sure we would be happy to help.

Comment: I suggest to narrow your question to fulfill @Ethan48 's requirements. Or, if it doesn't work, then ask the question on http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com - the answer you get there, will be useful to construct multiple, more specific, narrower questions here, too.

Comment: Deep carbon cuts are unlikely to help. Plot the temperature progression from the "litte ice age" on and see what it shows.